# Kotlin - Get maximum value with its key in a set

Tags: kotlin

I have a defined a set like below.

```
val resultSet: Set<Pair<Driver,Int>>
```

How to get maximum value of above `resultSet` set with its key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `maxBy` function. It returns the maximum value given by the extractor you pass to it, or null if the set is empty. You could do something like this:

```
val maxPair = resultSet.maxBy { it.second }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort by the `Int` value in the pair:

```kotlin
val max: Pair<Driver, Int> = resultSet.maxBy { it.second }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin 1.4 this method has been renamed to maxByOrNull or maxWithOrNull

```
    val maxPair = resultSet.maxByOrNull { it.second }
    val maxPair = resultSet.maxWithOrNull(compareBy {it.second})
```

**References:**

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-or-null.html

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html